# How to publish asynchronously with HiRedis

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

I am using HiRedis with a c/c++ program and have written some tests to verify that subscriptions work (I based my solution on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215977/1613983)).

However, currently I can only publish by manually typing something like `publish foo "abcd"` into the `redis-cli` terminal. This works as per the linked comment, but I'd like to publish *from* my c++ program. How can I do this?

I have tried this command:

```
redisAsyncCommand(c, SubCallback, (char*)"command", "publish foo \"abcd\"");
```

But that results in this runtime error:

> Error: ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context

How can I publish data from within HiRedis?

Comment: The same channel can be used for PUBLISH and PSUBSCRIBE when switching to RESP3 protocol, which can be done by sending "HELLO 3" command first.

Answer (score 1):

Once a connection context has subscribed, it can't be used to PUBLISH. You must create a new connection.

Comment: Can you provide some examples about how to Publish data to a topic?

Comment: The same channel can be used for PUBLISH and PSUBSCRIBE when switching to RESP3 protocol, which can be done by sending "HELLO 3" command first.

Answer (score -1):

from `https://github.com/redis/hiredis` in `hiredis/examples/example-libevent.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <hiredis.h>
#include <async.h>
#include <adapters/libevent.h>

void getCallback(redisAsyncContext *c, void *r, void *privdata) {
    redisReply *reply = r;
    if (reply == NULL) return;
    printf("argv[%s]: %s\n", (char*)privdata, reply->str);

    /* Disconnect after receiving the reply to GET */
    redisAsyncDisconnect(c);
}

void connectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status) {
    if (status != REDIS_OK) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return;
    }
    printf("Connected...\n");
}

void disconnectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status) {
    if (status != REDIS_OK) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return;
    }
    printf("Disconnected...\n");
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    struct event_base *base = event_base_new();

    redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        /* Let *c leak for now... */
        printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    redisLibeventAttach(c,base);
    redisAsyncSetConnectCallback(c,connectCallback);
    redisAsyncSetDisconnectCallback(c,disconnectCallback);
    redisAsyncCommand(c, NULL, NULL, "SET key %b", argv[argc-1], strlen(argv[argc-1]));
    redisAsyncCommand(c, getCallback, (char*)"end-1", "GET key");
    event_base_dispatch(base);
    return 0;
}
```