# How can I inform a thread running libevent that it should take some action?

Tags: c++, c, libevent

I am using libevent in a backend thread to run hiredis and subscribe to a remote redis database. The subscription works superbly using the simple examples from another SO question:

[Hiredis waiting for message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213676/hiredis-waiting-for-message)

However, in order to avoid race conditions it is not trivial to add subscriptions from the main thread. To achieve this I've created a `std::vector<std::string>` object containing any key strings that the backend should subscribe to. Reading to / from this vector is performed via a mutex.

However, how can I inform the backend that I've added some subscriptions? Currently I use a timer set to a very low resolution:

```
void Client::fireAndRequeueTimer(int fd, short e, void* arg)                        
{                                                                                   
    Client* client = reinterpret_cast<Client*>(arg); // the client handles the subscription to redis (via hiredis/libevent)                                                                                    
    if (client->mDisconnect)                            
        return; // the main thread wants us to exit, so we don't recreate the timer

    event* ev = &client->mTimerEvent; // some timer event object we created
    timeval tv;                                                                     
    tv.tv_sec = 0;                                                                  
    tv.tv_usec = 1000; // 1ms                                                       

    evtimer_add(ev, &tv);

    // mPendingSubscriptions is an std::vector of strings, which contain the keys that we should add subscriptions to.
    if (client->mPendingSubscriptions.size())                                       
    {                                                                               
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(client->mSubscriptionsMutex);             

        do                                                                          
        {                                                                           
            redisAsyncCommand(                                                      
                client->mContext,                                                
                Client::subCallback,                                                
                (char*)"sub",                                                       
                "SUBSCRIBE %s",                                                     
                client->mPendingSubscriptions.back().c_str());                      

            client->mPendingSubscriptions.pop_back();                               
        }                                                                           
        while (client->mPendingSubscriptions.size());                               
    }                                                                               
}
```

(note that I'm using `libevent 1.4.x` so features such as EV_PERSIST don't exist and I have to recreate the timer at each event).

While the above works, I am not happy with it for the following reasons:

1. It places unnecessary strain on the backend to continually poll the vector.
2. It is difficult for the reader to follow without extensive comments
3. It is slow; this timer will add as much as 1ms to the time it takes to subscribe to an event. This might be significant, or it might not, but either way it's a waste of time.

Are there any solutions to this problem that will address these concerns within the confines of `libevent 1.4.x`?

Comment: Not sure if libevent uses pthreads? If so, can you use a signal, e.g. SIGHUP, and set the pthread sigmask so only your backend thread will accept the signal?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to have the target thread add an [`eventfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) (or similar construct) to its event queue.

The `eventfd` can be notified from any other thread safely and cause the target thread to call the associated event handler.

This way, you do not need to worry about correctly locking the absolute minimum of the libevent structures, as the OS takes care of that for you.

Note: `eventfd` is not available on OSX, but can be easily emulated with a pipe as long as you do not require an extremely high rate of events.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. I'm guessing I would need to use something like `event_set(&event, fd, EV_READ, fn, data)`, but how do I a) get `fd` and b) "touch" fd to trigger the event?

Comment: I should clarify; I'm after a solution that is as portable as possible, so I'd like to avoid syscalls if possible.

Comment: There is `evutil_socketpair` that should create a similar solution, which I admittedly have never tried.